# Where to find emacs ansi-term bindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, ansi-term

I use extensively emacs' shell ansi-term but so far the way I discover the associated binding is by accidentally pressing keys, making something happening.

Do you know where I can find all the binding refering to ansi-term (or more generally, to a given emacs mode) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `describe-bindings` by pressing <kbd>f1</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, or <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-bindings`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.